# How much time does Janusgraph takes approximately to reindex if it has around 70G data

Tags: indexing, janusgraph

I have around 70G data in Janusgraph. I have planned to add a new index on the edge. Approximately how much time it could take to reindex?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think the answer to this question is straightforward. It depends on a lot on your infrastructure. Also depends on whether you plan to add a composite index or a mixed index. One thing i can say for sure is that it takes several minutes, if not hours. [This](https://docs.janusgraph.org/index-management/index-reindexing/) has more information and precautions you need to take while reindexing.

edit-@tanroop does this answer your question. accept if yes, or comment if you think otherwise thanks